# Write or Read Instructions in LLVM

Tags: llvm

I just wanted to make sure I understand getOperand() right. It seems like getOperand() return operands in a reverse order:

so if I have:

```
%1 = mul nsw i32 7, 2          # The c source code is: a = 7; b = a*2
ret i32 %1                     # The c source code is: return a;
```

Correct me if I'm wrong:

In the first instruction, getOperand(0) gives me 'i32' (what is being read) and getOpernad(1) 'nsw' (what is being written to).

In the second instruction, the only operand is i32 which is being read.

So I guess my question is, if the instruction is writing to something, is it the last operand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mul` instruction is multiplication, so no, its operand do not correspond to those C expressions. You see this instruction instead of `alloca`s and `store`s because Clang figured out your code is constant expression and propagated it. And AFAIK, there is nothing you can do to stop it - Clang performs constant propagation even with `-O0`.